# ABPersonViewController not locating address on map

Tags: ios5, geocoding, abpersonviewcontroller, addressbookui

Any ideas as to why presenting an ABPersonViewController with its delegate won't locate an address of a selected person on the map?

Currently, the app just quits to Maps and stays there zoomed out.

The code for the ABPersonViewController delegate just returns YES to any action performed on a contact, and, if I manually copy the person's address and paste it into the maps app, the given address is found without any issues.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!